# vb.net - List (Of String) Sorting, Numbers Ascending, Alphabet Descending

Tags: arrays, vb.net, list, sorting

I am trying to sort a list of string into a very particular order. I have a list of items which come in the format of "X123XXX" where X can be a letter, and the 123 can be any number.

```
Dim AList As New List(Of String)
AList.Add("B200")
AList.Add("A100X")
AList.Add("A100XY")
AList.Add("A100XYZ")

AList.Sort()

'Actual Return in order (AList(1).tostring etc.)
'A100X
'A100XY
'A100XYZ
'B200

'Desired Return
'A100XYZ
'A100XY
'A100X
'B200
```

The problem I have is that Not only do I need to sort the Numbers Ascending and Letters Descending, but I also need to sort the first letter Ascending.

I was hoping that, as the parts are always in the same format (letter + 3 numbers + Optional up to 3 letters) - that I could just select the first 4 and sort that ASC and then DESC on the last 3. But i have no idea how to do that in vb.net. I've had a look around, and can only find the IComparable stuff, which doesn't seem like it would be very useful.

Comment: always 3 numbers? I mean, 1 letter, 3 numbers, X letters?

Comment: Yes, they always have 3 numbers and 1 letter at the start. I may later have to make the letters at the start variable, but not for now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get what you want by relying on some `LINQ` methods (`OrderBy`, `ThenBy`, etc.); they allow you to perform all the modifications you need.

Code delivering what you want:

```
 AList = AList.OrderBy(Function(x) x.Substring(0, 1)).ThenBy(Function(x) Convert.ToInt32(x.Substring(1, 3))).ThenByDescending(Function(x) x.Substring(4)).ToList()
```

UPDATE

The code above orders the last part (i.e., letters from the 5th position until the end) in alphabetically descending order; but apparently the OP wants this last sorting to be performed on account of the length of the strings (i.e., longest one first and shortest one last). The following code delivers such a behaviour:

```
AList = AList.OrderBy(Function(x) x.Substring(0, 1)).ThenBy(Function(x) Convert.ToInt32(x.Substring(1, 3))).ThenByDescending(Function(x) x.Substring(4).Length).ToList()
```

Comment: @Thomas hi again. Thanks for the +1

Comment: Thank you varocarbas, this seems to have done the trick. I did think LINQ was the option, but haven't had enough experience.

Comment: @Feedel You are welcome. I hope that this code will help you to get started with LINQ.

Comment: @varocarbas - I thought i cracked it but i've realised an issue with the LINQ, well something i can't figure out at least. The last 3 character, ("K", "FK", "VFK"), are coming in wrong. it seems to just order the first letter, where as I need; VFK, FK, K, in that order. I apologies, i realize my example didn't really make this clear.

Comment: @Feedel It works exactly as I understood that you wanted it to work. That is: the last ordering is performed descendently on account of the last substring (i.e., from the 5th position until the end). In your example: XYZ is the biggest one, XY the second biggest one and X the smallest one. What you want exactly?

Comment: @Feedel VFG, FK, K is not the right descending order. The right descending order is: VFK, K & FK (what delivers the code I wrote). What do you want exactly? Just ordering by the number of letters? This can also be done, but you have to clearly define your expectations.

Comment: I realised my mistake after I went through the answer and implemented it, my apologies. In my example, I would like the longest word first, So in my example provided, it should read "XYZ", "XY" then "X" - however, in my real life product they do not begin with the same letters. I assumed that sorting in descending would sort strings by largest first, but i assumed wrong!

Comment: @Feedel No big deal. I will update my answer in 1 minute. Next time try to make sure that you describe your conditions properly; an example is usually a very good idea, but some times examples don't tell the whole story.

Comment: @Feedel There you have it. In any case, bear in mind that I have done an exception here: SO (at least, as I see it) is not for delivering custom-made codes working as per the exact requirements of the asker. I understand that you want to learn to use the LINQ methods and that's why I don't see any problem. But please use this site properly in the future (and write clear questions).

Comment: @varocarbas Thank you very much. I haven't written many questions on here. Haven't needed to really. I will take your advice and apply it in future. Have a good day!

Answer (score 2):

An alternate approach to the anonymous function, create a Class that implements `IComparer(Of String)`:

```
Private Class CodeComparer
    Implements System.Collections.Generic.IComparer(Of String)

    Function Compare(ByVal a As String, ByVal b As String) As Integer _
             Implements IComparer(Of String).Compare
        Dim result As Integer = a.Substring(0, 4).CompareTo(b.Substring(0, 4))
        If result = 0 Then
            result = a.Substring(4).CompareTo(b.Substring(4)) * -1
        End If
        Return result
    End Function
End Class
```

This sorts by the first 4 characters in ascending order, then by the remaining characters in decending order (hence the `* -1`).

You can then sort the list using:

```
items.Sort(New CodeComparer())
```

Edit:  You can also use the same algorithm with an anonymous function passed to the `Sort` method.

```
items.Sort(Function(a, b)
               Dim result As Integer = a.Substring(0, 4).CompareTo(b.Substring(0, 4))
               If result = 0 Then result = a.Substring(4).CompareTo(b.Substring(4)) * -1
               Return tmp
           End Function)
```

Comment: Using this method also makes it easier to debug (especially when running under the debugger in Visual Studio). You can add a breakpoint and verify the logic of the comparison.